# Unknown driver type "mpio"

Tags: python-2.7, h5py, ubuntu-13.04, mpi4py

I would appreciate if anyone could guide me towards a solution/understanding for the following error message :

```
f = h5py.File(filename, 'w', driver='mpio', comm=comm)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 149, in __init__
fapl = make_fapl(driver,libver,**kwds)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 37, in make_fapl
raise ValueError('Unknown driver type "%s"' % driver)
ValueError: Unknown driver type "mpio"
```

I installed h5py using the ubuntu software center. (I ran h5cc -showconfig and noted that parallel HDF5 was enabled.)

I am running on a macbook air with core 2 duo, with only one core enabled for a virtual desktop of ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of h5py that comes with Ubuntu was **not** built against parallel HDF5. That's why you can't use the MPI driver. You need to build h5py by hand. The most convenient way is to use a virtualenv environment, so that the parallel h5py version does not interfere with the Ubuntu-installed version. All you have to do is:

1. Unpack the h5py source code from h5py.org
2. Make sure you are in a virtualenv (or don't, if you prefer to install h5py globally. But then you better uninstall h5py in Ubuntu)
3. $ export CC=mpicc
4. $ python setup.py build --mpi
5. $ python setup.py install

That's it. See http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/mpi.html for details.

Comment: Can I do a local install? I am trying to install it on a system without root access.